# Why is my dictionary of trained models not predicting accurately?

Tags: django, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pickle

I have a lot of data on brands and items from those brands. What I'm doing is a GridSearch on a bunch of regression models and adding the best estimator to a dictionary. So it looks like this-

```
{'Kellogs': {'Fruit Loops': MLPRegressor(<best parameters>)}}
```

Then it predicts and 1 box costs $2.

Then I pickle it for use in a Django Application. The problem is that when I train it locally it runs SO accurately that it's hard to deny that it's right, but when I import 'trained_models.p' and call it like so- `trained_models[brand][cereal].predict(np.array(1).reshape(-1, 1)` predicts $12.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

All of the regressors contained in the dictionary need to be fit again in order to predict most accurately.

It usually doesn't take too long.